# Get days that are not present in a date range using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I got a list of dates that serves as attendance like

```
06/01/2012
06/02/2012
06/03/2012
06/06/2012
06/07/2012
06/08/2012
06/10/2012
06/13/2012
06/14/2012
06/15/2012
```

and i have this date range

```
 06/01/2012-06/15/2012
```

How would i get the dates that are not on the list but falls in the date range using linq..

Comment: Anything you have already tried and wanted to share?

Comment: actually this is to formulate the concept of attendance checking from a ef application i will edit the question

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
var dateList = new List<DateTime>
{
    new DateTime(2012, 06, 01),
    new DateTime(2012, 06, 02),
    //..etc
};

var startDate = new DateTime(2012, 06, 01);
var endDate = new DateTime(2012, 06, 15);

var dateRange =
    Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(endDate - startDate).TotalDays + 1)
    .Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i));

var datesNotMatched = dateRange.Except(dateList);
```

Comment: I guest except is what i missed I am using !.Any

Answer (score 2):

Let `inputDateList` be a List of strings representing the input dates, and `AttendanceDate` a List of DateTime corresponds to the input strings. Let me use `dateRangeStart` to denote the start range and `dateRangeEnd` for the range End. Then following code will filter the inputDateList within the range of dateRangeStart - dateRangeEnd.

```
DateTime inDate;
DateTime dateRangeStart;
DateTime dateRangeEnd;
List<string> inputDateList = new List<string>(){"06/01/2012",
                                          "06/02/2012",
                                          "06/03/2012",
                                          "06/06/2012",
                                          "06/07/2012",
                                          "06/08/2012",
                                          "06/10/2012",
                                          "06/13/2012",
                                          "06/14/2012",
                                          "06/17/2012"};

List<DateTime?> AttendanceDate = inputDateList.Select(x => DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out inDate) ? inDate : (DateTime?)null)
                                              .ToList();

DateTime.TryParseExact("06/01/2012", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateRangeStart);
DateTime.TryParseExact("06/15/2012", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateRangeEnd);

List<DateTime?> datesInRange = AttendanceDate.Where(x => x >= dateRangeStart && x <= dateRangeEnd).ToList();
```

`datesInRange` will be the required List of dates

Comment: @Kason : thanks for the down-vote, Which helps me to correct the error, `datesInRange` should be of type  `List<DateTime?>`. Thanks again